# Wordpress Site's home page is displaced by Cpanel's site publisher

Tags: wordpress

In my WordPress site, all the other pages are displaying properly but the home page is replaced by cpanel's site publisher coming soon page.

The site is indexing to the site publisher I have tried deleting the site publisher file using FTP, but the problem has not been resolved. Please suggest what I have supposed to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there's not a standard cPanel index.html file still in your websites main folder, as it gets read before wordpress' index.php file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).